# How can I create a custom module that allows multiple image upload fields?

Tags: files

To be a little more specific, I am trying to create a custom field which will contain 4 images and 4 corresponding paragraphs. The part that I am having issues with is allowing 4 image upload fields.

Answer (score 1):

No need for custom module, the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) contrib module will allow you to do that. See [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqtCv7KEUis).